# Pyspark groupby / agg function without changing the column names?

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, aggregate

In cases where I have a large number of columns that I want to sum, average, etc., is there a way to NOT change the column names, without having to use .alias on each column? The default is to add the function to the column name (e.g. col1 becomes "avg(col1)" after taking the average), is there an efficient way to have it stay named "col1"?

```
df = df.groupby(seg).avg('col1')
```

Comment: `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`: `df = df.groupby(seg).agg(F.col('col1').alias("col1"))`

Comment: Thank you! I'm aware of .alias, and that seems doable for a simple case, but I'm actually taking the average of all the columns in the df (excluding the one in the groupby), so I'm not calling them specifically in the "avg", I'm just using avg() [empty parentheses], so trying to avoid having to use .alias 20+ times, plus I think I'd no longer be able to take advantage of the empty parenthesis behavior that automatically applies the function to all columns

Comment: hmm, you can still loop : `df.groupby(seg).agg([*F.col(i).alias(i) for i in df.columns if not i in seg])`